# Randomly getting Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded in zone.js

Tags: angular

We're using Bugsnag and randomly I see this error in our logs

[image: error]

We're on Angular 6.1.1, and we're using production build with optimization and build-optimization enabled. Using zone.js 0.8.26 which is currently latest version.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Are you using the latest zone.js. I think the same issue has been fixed [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/886)

Comment: We're on 0.8.26 which is latest version. I found your post as well, but that's unfortunately not the issue here.

Comment: Are the errors generated by random users or only some browser/OS configurations?

Comment: Couldn't find a pattern yet @Blender

Comment: Do you have routing in the app?

Comment: Yes @RayLuxembourg we have, why? Thanks.

Comment: This usually happens to me when I forget to include routing inside lazy loaded module. If you recently made changes to route and i am right try removing new changed routes and see if the changes solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find a way to reproduce this error, after that you can try to downgrade zone.js version, try to temporary remove third party libraries (WS libraries, bugsnap itself, all other libraries that might be using advanced browser features and prototype patches), ensure that zone.js is loaded first, relax uglify-js settings. Also you may be interested in https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/900.

Comment: Yeah but I have no idea how to reproduce the error. It only seems to happen on production, so can't just remove / add 3rd party  libraries. Isn't there any use in the stacktrace provided?

Comment: Stacktrace is generic and caused by logical error, not just simple nullpointer exception.