# Randomly Maximum Call Stack Exceeded with Subject.js in stack trace

Tags: angular, rxjs

We see a lot of *Call Stack Exceeded* errors in Bugsnag, see also my [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777669/randomly-getting-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-in-zone-js). I've now been able to see the error in the console as well, but no idea how to reproduce it. It just randomly happens.
We are using a lot of subscriptions between components and services. We're destroying them properly as previously we had a memory leak.

No idea how to reproduce it or where the error comes from, but it's better than the previous error. Any idea where we should look for this issue?

[image]

Comment: There are a bunch of `next` calls in there. Given that it's a call-stack error, I'd speculate that you might have a cycle somewhere in which two subjects are subscribed to one another - either directly or indirectly.

Comment: These are almost impossible to debug.. Try increasing the call stack output by using Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; Then look for patterns inside that

Comment: Are you using `takeUntil` together with `concatMap` in the same chain somewhere in the code?

Comment: @m1ch4ls no we're not using takeUntil.

Comment: I've added a feature to [`rxjs-spy`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-spy/) to detect cyclic `next` calls and to report the location of the root subscription for the first such cyclic call. If you've not yet solved the problem, it might be of some use.